# Use Joomla 2.5 Databse Instance in Custom Jumi Module

Tags: joomla

I am using Joomla 2.5.

I want to use Joomla DB instance in my Custom Jumi Module so that i don't have to create new db connection. Is there any way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this is what you are looking for:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO(); //code for database connection
$query = 'SELECT * FROM #__tablename'; //selects from table
$db->setQuery($query);
```

Comment: you see the tick button on the left hand side of my answer? :)